# python pandas. Найти максимальное число колонки

Tags: python, pandas

У меня есть Датафрейм в котором около 300 строк и 15 столбцов. В данном вопросе меня интересуют всего два столбца, назову их 'A' и 'B'.
У столбца 'A' есть всего несколько чисел ( допустим 101,102,103 ), а в столбце 'B' множество различных числе от 0 до 9999. Я хочу сделать подсчёт максимального числа столбца 'B' для каждого из чисел 'A'.
Например:
101 = 573 ( максимальное встречаемое число в колонке 'B', но с учётом что 'A' = 101 )
102 = 1237
103 = 5317

ниже визуальный пример

[image: Пример]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Класс!
Пошли вопросы от людей, не удосужившихся прочитать 5 страниц документации или учебника по тому инструменту, который они используют.

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame({'A':[101,102,102,103,101,103,102],'B':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7],'C':[1,1,2,3,4,5,3]})
df.groupby('A')['B'].max()
```

Результат:

```
 A
101    5
102    7
103    6
```

Впрочем, я сделал свою интерпретацию очень загадочной фразы,  *"**подсчёт максимального числа** столбца 'B' "*. Может я и не угадал?